# How can I read csv file using apache camel only once from http?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

I try to create a route, that can access http url with csv file and simply print the content of it. Unfortunately the file is being read continuously.

1. Is it possible to do read it only once and then stop processing?
2. Why does "direct:start" not work in this example and I have to use timer?

Here is my code:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("timer://start?delay=5000")
                        .to("http4://127.0.0.1:18080/data.csv")
                        .unmarshal().csv()
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                String list = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                log.info(list);
                  //Here I would like to stop the route when file reading is finished
                            }
                        });
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at the official documentation? [http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html)

Answer (score 2):

The timer will keep calling every 5th seconds. If you only want to call the timer one time, you can set `repeatCount=1`: http://camel.apache.org/timer

But you may need to consider do you want to only let it run once. What if you need to call that HTTP url again sometime later?

And also as Frank commented there is a way to stop a route from a route: http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Comment: Yes.., @Peters_ , It's a matter of adding exception handling in your routes . 1. What If the http call failed because of connectivity issues ? 2. Or if there is a connectivity exception ? Also you might want to execute this route atleast once everyday ? There are so many things you can do, it depends on what use case you wanna achieve.

Comment: Actually I would like to start this route everytime when  http requests comes to my second route which uses jetty for listening on another port. When there is http request I would like to start main route, process csv file and stop route. It should be possible to repeat it.